# Using BeautifulSoup to search for element by src tag

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

Let's say I'm scraping a webpage, and I want to select a certain image on the webpage.  Just as you can find elements based on their class name, I want to select an image by its `src` tag.  How would I select an image where I already know the `src` tag?

i.e. I want to select the image whose `src` tag is:

```
https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/pin.svg
```

Answer (score 5):

You can search by arbitrary attributes; this should work:

```
soup.findAll("img", {"src" : "https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/pin.svg"})
```

Answer (score 1):

While @Blorgbeard's answer shows the `Beautifulsoup` approach, using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you can achieve the same using either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  my_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[src=\"https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/pin.svg\"]")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  my_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@src=\"https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/pin.svg\"]")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Using Beautifulsoup you can do it many ways. You can use css selector , you can use regular expression as well.

**Css Selector**

```
for item in soup.select('img[src="https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/pin.svg"]'):
   print(item['src'])
```

**Regular Expression** with find_all

```
import re
for item in soup.find_all('img',src=re.compile('https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/pin.svg')):
   print(item['src'])
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of using a regex for an exact string match is. Those `.` are supposed to be literal, but regex will interpret that as "any character".

Comment: Here regex will search entire string.However this an options if any other future readers needs to search particular value by regex.

Comment: Yes, it's useful to know you can use regex that way (I didn't actually know that myself), but it doesn't really make sense with the given example. Something like `src=re.compile('https://.*\.bandsintown\.com/.*/pin\.svg')` might be a better illustration of what you could do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You said a single image by its `src` value. Use `select_one`. Less work and you only need an attribute selector.

```
soup.select_one('[src="https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/pin.svg"]')['src']
```